# $(document).ready(function() vs .click(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a page that is populated with a $.getJSON() function which is working perfectly, the JSON is being written into the DOM correctly but I have another function that toggles the display of elements on a page if there is a matching value in the query string.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#one").toggle(data.indexOf("one") !== -1);
    $("#two").toggle(data.indexOf("two") !== -1);
    $("#three").toggle(data.indexOf("three") !== -1);
    $("#four").toggle(data.indexOf("four") !== -1);
});
```

If I use any other event to fire the function the correct elements are hidden/displayed on the page for example.

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $("#one").toggle(data.indexOf("one") !== -1);
    $("#two").toggle(data.indexOf("two") !== -1);
    $("#three").toggle(data.indexOf("three") !== -1);
    $("#four").toggle(data.indexOf("four") !== -1);
});
```

Can someone please explain why the .ready() function is not working?

Interestingly loading the content of the page with a $.getJSON() function seems to have something to do with it because if I hard code the HTML then my .ready() function works.

Cheers Jeff

Comment: The code in the "ready" handler fires when the page is complete. The code in the "click" handler fires only when you click the mouse on something. Your `$.getJSON()` is asynchronous, so the first won't work if the page completes before the response to that comes back.

Comment: What is `data`? What is written into the DOM - are the `#one, #two, #three, #four` elements generated from the JSON?

Comment: The data variable is what is being passed to the page in the query string and yes the elements are being written into the DOM from a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ready event is fired when your dom page is loaded.

Your getJSON() function is triggered after the dom is loaded !

Add a promise to your getJSON code to change it.

```
.getJSON().then(function() {
   $("#one").toggle(data.indexOf("one") !== -1);
   $("#two").toggle(data.indexOf("two") !== -1);
   $("#three").toggle(data.indexOf("three") !== -1);
   $("#four").toggle(data.indexOf("four") !== -1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I had some idea it was something to do with the DOM but was unsure of the solution, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` doesn't wait for your asynchronous call (`$.getJSON()`) to complete, so the ready event is fired before the page has been populated and the elements you want to manipulate don't exist yet.

When you hard-code the data it works because it doesn't have to wait for an asynchronous request to finish and the page gets populated immediately.

The easiest solution is to invoke the event handler function right after the page has been populated by the callback function for the `$.getJSON()` call. Hopefully you already have some mechanism in that callback function to make sure it doesn't populate the page if the request finished before the ready event was fired.